# Pairs and Lists of pairs

Tags: haskell, tuples, lookup

Say I had a pair and a list of pairs. How would I check if any character (first or second) in the pair is already in the list of pairs (again any element and either first or second)?

Comment: how do you try this task?

Answer (score 1):

A straitforward implementation would be:

```
containsAny :: (Char, Char) -> [(Char, Char)] -> Bool
containsAny (a, b) = any (\(x, y) -> a == x || a == b || a == x || a == y)
```

and you could make it more general if you specify the type as

```
containsAny :: Eq a => (a, a) -> [(a, a)] -> Bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward approach:

```
f :: (Char, Char) -> [(Char, Char)] -> Bool
f (a,b) xs = any (\x -> x == a || x == b) ((map fst xs) ++ (map snd xs))
```

We first construct a lazy list which is a flattening of the structure; the concatenation of all the first elements and all the second elements. Then we iterate through that list with `any`, using a lambda to that checks whether the element in the list matches either of the elements passed as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.Functor
f (x, y) pairs = x `elem` allValues || y `elem` allValues
    where allValues = (fst <$> pairs) ++ (snd <$> pairs)
```

Comment: I would recommend finding another name than `all`, which is already a function in the Prelude. ;)

Comment: @kqr, fair enough, I'll just change the sequence of numbers to a variable named "sequence" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The lensy solution could be

```
import Control.Lens

f (x, y) pairs = anyOf (traverse.both) (\c -> c == x || c == y) pairs
```

Tested as

```
λ> f ('p', 'o') [('h','e'),('l','l'),('o','w'),('o','r'),('l','d')]
True
λ> f ('q', 'v') [('n', 'o'), ('p', 'e')]
False
```

`lens` contains a lot of useful combinators for when you want to pry into data structures. `anyOf` takes three arguments:

1. A traversal that indicates which elements in the structure you are interested in,
2. A predicate that you want to hold for at least one of those elements, and
3. The data structure you're looking into.

`traverse` is a traversal that indicates every element of a list, and `both` is a traversal that indicates both elements of a pair, so `traverse.both` is a traversal that indicates both elements of all the pairs in a list of pairs.